# Parse exception with mercurial

Tags: mercurial, google-code

I have a huge project using googlecode/mercurial with the mercurial plugin on eclipse to manage and i am now unable to update or merge my repository. I cant explain how but it seem that i have a changeset corrupted!

This hapened when i create a new branch from another branch. I tried to reverse (dont remember how) because i made a mistake, after i create another one from the good branch, i commit , push, the problem happend!

This is what i see when i try to update or merge:
Parse exception '1062:d5d1c.....' see error log for more details

I will be very grateful if someone can help me. this project is very important!

Comment: Are you using tortoisehg or something along those lines? I don't know that I've ever seen that error out of Mercurial.